# Is it possible to rewrite $\sum_{k=1}^{N} B_{k}AB_{k}^{H}$ under the form $X_{1}AX_{2}$ ($B_{k}$, $A$, and $X_{i}$ are matrices)?

Tags: matrices, summation

Is there any way we could rewrite the sum

$$\sum_{k=1}^{N} B_{k}AB_{k}^{H} \tag{1}$$

under a form $$X_{1}AX_{2},$$

where $B_{k}$, $A$, and $X_{i}$ are matrices? The closest thing I was able to find about sums of this form was eq.275 from the [matrixcookbook](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ehwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf), but it isn't the form I am looking for unfortunately. Is there any remarkable identity related to (1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no.

Denote by $E_{i,j}$ the $N\times N$ matrix with 1 in the $(i,j)$ entry and zeros elsewhere.

Setting $A=E_{1,1}$ and $B_k=E_{k,1}$, for $k=1,\ldots,N$, we have that (1) in the statement of the question becomes the identity matrix $I$.  However, it is impossible to represent $I$ in the form $X_1AX_2$, since the latter has rank at most 1.

Answer (score 1):

**Lemma 1:** Any linear function $f：ℝ^{m×n}→ℝ^{k×l}$ can be written in the form $X⟼∑_{i=1}^{r} A_i X B_i^⊤$ for some $A_i∈ℝ^{k×m}$ and $B_i∈ℝ^{l×n}$.

**Lemmma 2:** Any linear function $f：ℝ^{m×n}→ℝ^{k×l}$ can be written in the standard form $X⟼ \big(∑_{mn} _{kl, mn} X_{mn}\big)_{kl} ≕ ⋅X$ for some 4th order tensor $∈ℝ^{k×l}⊗(ℝ^{m×n})^*$.

To go from form 1 to form 2 is via

$$∑_{i=1}^{r} A_i X B_i^⊤ = ∑_{i=1}^{r} (A_i⊗B_i)⋅ X = \big(\underbrace{∑_{i=1}^{r} (A_i⊗B_i)}_{=}\big)⋅ X$$

Using the convention $(A⊗B)_{ij, kl} = A_{ik}B_{jl}$.